# Converting column into row using awk

Tags: python, awk

I have 3 file data in form of column

data1 -> asec_1.txt

```
a,1,
b,2,
c,3,
```

data2 -> asec_2.txt

```
a,10,
b,11,
c,12,
```

data3 -> asec_3.txt

```
a,19,
b,20,
c,21,
```

And I want python or awk code for convert one data file per row in csv file

```
Data,a,b,c
Data_1,1,2,3
Data_2,10,11,12
Data_3,19,20,21
```

How to use for loop for each data file per row in csv file

Comment: Read the files to dict with first column as index & second as value, them using ``csv`` module dump to file.

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Do the following:

```
echo `cat asec_1.csv | tr -d "\n"` | sed -e "s/,$//" > res.csv
echo `cat asec_2.csv | tr -d "\n"` | sed -e "s/,$//" >> res.csv
echo `cat asec_3.csv | tr -d "\n"` | sed -e "s/,$//" >> res.csv
```

And you're done.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

This will work with GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) (required for `ENDFILE`)

```
awk '
  FNR==NR{h=h OFS $1}
  {s=s OFS $2}
  ENDFILE{
    if(!f){
      print "Data" h
      f=1
    }
    print "Data_" ++cnt s
    s=""
  }' FS=, OFS=, asec_*.txt
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{h=h OFS $1}{s=s OFS $2}ENDFILE{if(!f){print "Data" h; f=1}print "Data_" ++cnt s;s=""}' FS=, OFS=, asec_*
Data,a,b,c
Data_1,1,2,3
Data_2,10,11,12
Data_3,19,20,21
```